# get http url parameter without auto decoding using PHP

Tags: php, http, get

I have a url like

```
test.php?x=hello+world&y=%00h%00e%00l%00l%00o
```

when i write it to file

```
file_put_contents('x.txt', $_GET['x']); // -->hello world
file_put_contents('y.txt', $_GET['y']); // -->\0h\0e\0l\0l\0o
```

but i need to write it to without encoding

```
file_put_contents('x.txt', ????); // -->hello+world
file_put_contents('y.txt', ????); // -->%00h%00e%00l%00l%00o
```

how can i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can get unencoded values from the $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] variable.

```
function getNonDecodedParameters() {
  $a = array();
  foreach (explode ("&", $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]) as $q) {
    $p = explode ('=', $q, 2);
    $a[$p[0]] = isset ($p[1]) ? $p[1] : '';
  }
  return $a;
}

$input = getNonDecodedParameters();
file_put_contents('x.txt', $input['x']);
```

Comment: This is the right answer, since the re-encoding suggested by Ben D. treats some characters (like slashes) differently.

Answer (score 5):

Because the The `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` superglobals are automatically run through a decoding function (equivalent to `urldecode()`), you simply need to re-`urlencode()` the data to get it to match the characters passed in the URL string:

```
file_put_contents('x.txt', urlencode($_GET['x'])); // -->hello+world
file_put_contents('y.txt', urlencode($_GET['y'])); // -->%00h%00e%00l%00l%00o
```

I've tested this out locally and it's working perfectly. However, from your comments, you might want to look at your encoding settings as well. If the result of `urlencode($_GET['y'])` is `%5C0h%5C0e%5C0l%5C0l%5C0o` then it appears that the `null character` that you're passing in (`%00`) is being interpreted as a literal string `"\0"` (like a `\` character concatenated to a `0` character) instead of correctly interpreting the `\0` as a single null character.

You should have a look at the [PHP documentation on string encoding and ASCII device control characters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details).

Comment: not working. it return  x-->hello+world , y--> %5C0h%5C0e%5C0l%5C0l%5C0o

Comment: @user1725661 - Then something else is going on. I just tested this and it works fine... see my expanded answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use `urlencode()` to pass the value in URL and `urldecode()` to get the value.

Comment: not working. it return x-->hello+world , y--> %5C0h%5C0e%5C0l%5C0l%5C0o