# How to replace characters from string from url with PHP new lines?

Tags: php, html, url

I am not very used to PHP, so I would appreciate a simple solution (if possible).

I have an url that looks like that:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?text=hello%0A%0Ahow%20are%20you
```

I would like to send the text in an email with the basic mail() function. 
What happens when I send the email is that all new lines (%0A) are not converted to \r\n. I heard that $_GET[] automatically decodes the url, so I tried to encode it again using urlencode() function and then replacing all "%0A" with "\r\n" by using str_replace.

See me code so far:

```
$txt = urlencode($_GET['text']);
$txt = str_replace("%0A", "\r\n", $txt);
// no new line breaks
```

Unfortunately, there still was no line break in the mail (plain text).

Could you help me with that?

Google couldn't help me so far.

Thank you!

Comment: Try this function nl2br()
Source: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_nl2br.asp

Comment: Why not [urldecode(string): string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) directly? BTW, I've a doubt about "`$_GET[]` automatically decodes the url"; have you checked it?

Comment: Why `str_replace` on the `urlencode`d character? A new line in a URL unencoded isn't going to load as a new line.

Comment: @Odepax see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540117/get-http-url-parameter-without-auto-decoding-using-php

Comment: @Odepax Direct from the source `The GET variables are passed through urldecode().` -http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in this way.

```
<?php
$text= "hello%0A%0Ahow%20are%20you";
$txt = urldecode($text);
echo nl2br($txt);
```

[Click here for demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/25be1cfb90b9854b3eaf95ab0e8549f71c26c1b7)

Comment: But why do any of this?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The `$_GET` wouldn't have `%0A` in it. After `urldecode` the `%0A` isn't going to be that. The issue seems to be later in the process anyway.

Comment: @KamranJabbar Thanks, but that's not what I wanted to have; I need to work with the url, so I have to use $_GET and do some stuff after that.

Comment: $text string will be from URL you can replace my hard coded string to $_GET['text']